# Will Boost's float128 type work on Visual C++?

Tags: c++, precision, boost-multiprecision

This might be a stupid question, because why would they design it for a library if it's only for compilers that already support float128.

I just want to make sure before I download the library. Couldn't find the answer online. [Here's what I'm referring to.](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats/float128.html) It says that it's a "very thin wrapper" around GCC's and Intel's 128-bit floating-point types and that makes me think it's dependent on them existing and won't work for Visual C++.

Comment: See also https://github.com/boostorg/multiprecision/issues/13